# How to select from different table by case when

Tags: sql-server

I have some tables with different data, but them have the same column `UserId`:

If you declare like that :

```
declare @Type nvarchar(max) = 'Video';
declare @Id nvarchar(max)='M00000000007199';
declare @UserIdTable TABLE (UserId bigint)
```

Then I want to insert value into `@UserIdTable` by `@Type`, and I imaged :

```
insert into @UserIdTable 
case when @Type=Video then
  select UserId from VideoTable
else
  select UserId from TvTable
end
```

I know that is wrong, what should I do for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** which can return a value - it is **not** a flow control statement like in C# or VB.NET, and it cannot contain SQL statements or code blocks.

You'll need to rewrite your code to use a regular `IF .. THEN ... ELSE` statement - something like this:

```
IF @Type = Video 
   INSERT INTO @UserIdTable 
      SELECT UserId FROM dbo.VideoTable
ELSE
   INSERT INTO @UserIdTable 
      SELECT UserId FROM dbo.TvTable
```

Comment: when i remove the "THEN" and "END", it work!, thanks, that help a lot

Comment: @user3057975: ah - yeah - old habits die hard :-) Updated my post to remove those unneeded keywords.